# The screw of the SSD that fastens it to the motherboard is broken and the MacBook Air (Mid 2012) does not recognize it

Tags: ssd, macbook, screws

The screw that fastens the SSD to the motherboard was broken and now the MacBook Air (Mid 2012) does not recognize the SSD drive.

Also someone glued it with instant glue, even under the screw you see the part that I think is copper.

Is this the reason why it does not recognize the SSD or will it have a repair?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you have a picture of the SSD itself? Your pics just show the space where the SSD should be not the SSD itself which — honestly — might be damaged.

Comment: I add the pictures to the original question, thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks for adding the pic! Honestly, this does not seem like an issue with the screw. It’s most likely an issue with the SSD itself or the connector on the MacBook Air itself. But the screw is not — in my honest opinion — the source of this issue.

Comment: Ok many thanks man, i will try different things and if do not work, to hell with the mac, i really appreciate your help thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Broken screw can't be a problem for electrical functionality of SSD. Something else electrically went wrong. You can try another known-good SSD to see if the problem is on mainboard or on the SSD side. SSDs do die, and maybe even faster than HDDs. Your best course of action is to throw the nearly decade-old macbook away and get a new one.